# Persistent image storage in iOS

Tags: ios, image, storage, nsuserdefaults

Im using this method in order to store images and it is to my understanding that this method stores data persistently. The problem is that when I restart the simulator al the images are gone/unable to load.
Anyway here's the code:

```
- (NSString *)saveImage:(NSMutableString*)account{
        NSString *dir=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:dir];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", account,@"Banner.png"];
        NSString *imagePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:imageName];
        NSLog((@"pre writing to file"));
        NSError *writeError = nil;
        if(![imageData writeToFile:imagePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError]){
            NSLog(@"%@: Error saving image: %@",[self class], [writeError localizedDescription]);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"the cachedImagePath is %@", imagePath);
            return imagePath;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

This is the method used to load the image:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bannerPath]
```

bannerPath is the imagePath returned from the saving method stored in NSUserDefaults.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it? 
Thanks.

edit: I check with the following method if the file exists:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bannerPath];
```

I returns false.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart the simulator"? And how are you saving the imagePath?

Comment: I'm running the app in a simulator of an iPhone 6, the one included in Xcode, and i meant to say I close the simulator and run the app again. I'm saving the imagePath in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *imagePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:imageName];
```

i think should be

```
NSString *imagePath =    [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

`NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", account,@"Banner.png"];`

is missing a /, it should be

`NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@%@", account,@"Banner.png"];`

You were writing an image name "***DocumentsxxxxBanner.png***" in directory

/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D523E2E5-0B28-4D0D-8187-67D50A628481/data/Containers/Data/Application/82F36569-C3C0-46D9-AF60-044F7B484724/

instead of an image named "***xxxxBanner.png***" in directory

/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D523E2E5-0B28-4D0D-8187-67D50A628481/data/Containers/Data/Application/82F36569-C3C0-46D9-AF60-044F7B484724/**Documents**

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it's still not working.

Comment: Works here, do you see file in your app's Documents directory ?

Comment: I checked if it was getting saved with this funtion: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bannerPath];

It returns false. So its not getting saved properly. Any idea why?

Comment: Check file with finder on your hard disk please. [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bannerPath] is returning YES for me for info.

Comment: Its not there. I believe the problem is that every time I run the app the app gets installed in a different directory.

Comment: Version 6.4 (6E35b) here, there is something with your project launching in a different directory every time, could you create a new project and check if it's acting the same ?

Comment: I think every time I run the app is like the app its getting installed all over again.

Comment: Did you tried with a new simple project to see if it behaves the same way ?